# Prime Factor Program

Tags: python, prime-factoring

Problem
Here is the problem I am trying to solve.

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13, 29.  What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143?

```
def prime_calc():
    num = raw_input("What is the number you want the primes for?")
    prim_num = []
    x = 2
    while num/x > 1:
        new_num = num / x
        if num % x == 0:
            return prim_num.append(x)
        elif num % x != 0:
            new_num = num/x += 1
            return prim_num.append(x)
        else:
            break
```

I keep getting an invalid syntax error starting from the bottom up to the fourth line that doesnt like my "+=" operator

Comment: `num/x += 1` isn't this two variables returning a primitive? Would += work on it in a scenario here? Why not just `num/x + 1`?

Comment: your code has multiple flaws. the first of all is you are dividing a `str` type with a `int` type.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
new_num = num/x += 1
```

should be broken into two lines:

```
x += 1
new_num = num/x
```

The statement `x += 1` in python doesn't return anything, so you can't use it as part of an expression.

Similarly, the two instances of:

```
return prim_num.append(x)
```

Also won't work, since the statement: `prime_num.append(x)` doesn't return anything.
You need to break this into:

```
prime_num.append(x)
return prime_num
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num=int(input("Please enter number to calculate prime factor"))    
k=0    
item=[]    
if(num%2==0):    
  prime=2    
  item.insert(k,prime)    
  k=k+1    

j=3    
flag=int(num/2)    
while(j<flag and num>2):    
  if num%j==0:    
    prime=j
    item.insert(k,prime)
    k=k+1
    num=num/j
    j=j+2
  else:
    j=j+2

if k==0:    
  print("sorry no prime factor for this number")    
else:    
  print("Please find the largest prime factor below")
  print(item.pop())
```